# Orchard CMS IContentQuery subqueries?

Tags: c#, sql, orchardcms

I am building a query for contents in the code of a module I am building for a back-end using Orchard CMS (version 1.8).

I am trying to get contents that do not have a translation to a specific culture.

I was able to write a SQL query and test it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

```
SELECT [Id]
  ,[CultureId]
  ,[MasterContentItemId]
  FROM [Orchard_MyTenant].[dbo].[Orchard_Localization_LocalizationPartRecord]
  WHERE [CultureId] != 1
  AND [Id] NOT IN (
    SELECT [MasterContentItemId]
      FROM [Orchard_MyTenant].[dbo].[Orchard_Localization_LocalizationPartRecord]
  WHERE [Id] IN (
    SELECT [Id] 
    FROM [Orchard_FestivalTV].[dbo].[Orchard_Localization_LocalizationPartRecord]
    WHERE [CultureId] = 1
  )
)
```

I understand this only finds the untranslated cultures from the Master culture, and would not, for example, given en-US as the master culture, would not find French contents that are not translated in Italian. I can make that improvement later.

I have no idea how to implement this using IContentQuery, and I have to use those because this functionality would be a part of a larger module, where the query is already built like that.

I am able to make this query using QueryOver, but I'd rather not go and change all the legacy code that is already in place.

Could anyone explain how this could be implemented using IContentQuery?

Let me know if I forgot any useful information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a multilingual site and you want to be able to check for a specific Content Type which Content Items of that Type have not yet been translated into a specific language. For example, your site's default culture is `en-US` and you also support `fr-FR` and `it-IT`. Now you want to know which `MyTenant` Content Items have not been translated into `fr-FR` yet.

Assuming that's what you want to achieve, the following should work:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ContentItem> GetUntranslatedTenants(int cultureId)
{
    var allTenants = _contentManager.Query().ForType("MyTenant").List();
    var untranslatedTenants = allTenants
    .Where(x => x.As<LocalizationPart>().MasterContentItem == null &&
        !allTenants.Any(y => y.As<LocalizationPart>().MasterContentItem == x &&
        y.As<LocalizationPart>().Culture.Id == cultureId));

    return untranslatedTenants;
}
```

This code fetches all ContentItems that don't have a MasterContentItem, which are the MasterContentItems themselves, and for which there are no ContentItems who have them as a MasterContentItem that are translated into the specified culture.

This is a pretty complicated query though and the performance might not be great. Alternatively you could inject Orchard's `ILocalizationService` which has a `IEnumerable<LocalizationPart> GetLocalizations(IContent content);` method and use that to check if the localizations you get contain one for the specified culture.

I think the key thing to remember is that you can fetch MasterContentItems by looking for ContentItems that don't have a MasterContentItem themselves.

Comment: That method works, and is basically what I had already implemented. I have to apologize for not being clear in my question: the query, in my case, may return way too many contentItems for me to want to put everything in an IEnumerable and then filter it with Linq. I was wondering if there was a way to insert this "filter" directly in the IContentQuery.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah that makes sense. It's a common problem with Orchard that content queries can get really slow fast and as far as I'm aware there's no super elegant solution. If you're feeling adventurous, you can query the Orchard tables directly through NHibernate. Have a look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/querying-orchard-in-hql

Comment: Hello, I can get the results by usng NHibernate,  HQL, or QueryOver. However, I don't want to, because that would force me to go and change all the code this feature has to work with, where I build a big query based on the contents of a form (everything else I do with IContentQuery). I am aso a bit worried whenever I use something different than IContentQuery, because I fear that in different versions of Orchard they may slightly change the tables, forcing me to review all my custom queries.

Comment: You could convert your results to an IContentQuery but that doesn't eliminate your last concern - the tables changing. I don't think there is any way to add these kinds of constraints directly to the query and I agree that there really should be. Maybe if you leverage the lazy nature of the query and include QueryHints for the parts and records that you know need to be fetched, you could make your existing code about as performant.

Comment: Marked this as an answer because I fear it is as close as we can get to what I want in my specific case.

Comment: @Bovaz Cheers but I hope someone comes along and proves us wrong.